# vim: Enable online html checker for syntastic?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Googled around on how to do this and looked at the syntastic docs a bit, but they only confused me more.

Looking [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/HTML:---validator) I enabled an html checker for syntastic via an online service. Here are all the lines relating to syntastic I have in my _vimrc:

```
"syntastic
let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
" On by default, turn it off for html
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
    \ 'active_filetypes': ['html'] }
"   \ 'passive_filetypes': ['html'] }
"validators\checkers
let g:syntastic_html_validator_api='http://validator.nu/'
```

Running SyntasticInfo it does not appear to find the html checker?
[image]

Am I just not understanding how this works? Sorry, I'm very new to vim in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about this question. I did post on the plugin's issue tracker and was told it required curl to be installed- I was also told this info would now be included in the plugins description. I'm running Windows so its not as easy as apt-get install curl, but I think I can figure it out. Actually if you follow that link you will see curl under requirements.